# Runtime error 91 object variable or with variable not set

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

when the code gets to the 'find first empty row in database it highlights the next two rows in yellow and shows runtime error 91. can anyone please advise where i am going wrong. thankyou.

```
Private Sub diaryenter_Click()
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("sheet1")
    'find first empty row in database
    iRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1
    'copy the data to the database
    With ws
      .Cells(iRow, 115).Value = Me.autodatet.Value
      .Cells(iRow, 116).Value = Me.fdcomments.Value
      .Cells(iRow, 121).Value = Me.fdgs.Value
    End With
    'clear the data
    Me.autodatet.Value = ""
    Me.fdcomments.Value = ""
    Me.fdgs.Value = ""
    Diaryentryf.Hide
    ThisWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Comment: on which line does error occur?

Comment: `xlByRows` not `xlRows`.

Comment: Is there any data in Worksheets("sheet1")? Otherwise it will error as nothing found

Comment: Hmm, looks oddly familiar... (it's *still* not a database)   ;-)

Answer (score 2):

It is `xlByRows` not `xlRows`.

```
iRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                     SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1
```

Comment: That is why one should use `Option Explicit` !

Comment: It seems to work even with xlRows does this affect the actual mechanism?

Comment: I just double-checked in the Immediate window. Actually, both xlByRows and xlRows return 1 so they are in fact interchangeable.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe add a test that there is actually data to stop .Find erroring if there is nothing to find.

```
  If Application.WorksheetFunction.Counta(ws.UsedRange) = 0 Then
        iRow = 1
   Else
        iRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                             SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1
   End If
```

And credit to @Jeeped for xlByRows.

Answer (score 0):

Carrying on from @QHarr comment you should check to see if the `FIND` finds anything
(if it doesn't it can't return the row number of the cell it didn't find).

```
Sub Test1()

    Dim rLastCell As Range
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Worksheets("sheet1")

    Set rLastCell = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If rLastCell Is Nothing Then
        iRow = 1
    Else
        iRow = rLastCell.Row+1
    End If

End Sub
```

Edit - was going to delete as QHarr gave a similar answer, but the method of finding if it's nothing is different.